# Why am I getting this foreign key error in my phoenix tests?

Tags: testing, elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I've got the following test in Phoenix:

```
test "list_orders/0 returns all orders" do
  {:ok, user} = %User{}
                |> User.changeset(@user_attrs)
                |> Repo.insert()

  changeset = %Order{}
              |> Order.changeset(@valid_attrs)
              |> Ecto.Changeset.put_change(:user_id, user.id)

  {:ok, order} = Repo.insert(changeset)

  assert MWS.list_orders() == [order]
end
```

Which is failing to insert `changeset` into the `Repo` because `user_id` is failing a foreign key constraint. But I'm using the `user.id` that's returned from the user successfully being inserted into the database?

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you include your schema and changesets, and also the actual error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Kalvin Hom points out, you need to look at the schema/migrations to understand this:

```
defmodule BarronWatchCompany.Repo.Migrations.AddUsersToOrders do
  use Ecto.Migration

  def change do

    alter table(:orders) do
      add :user_id, references(:orders, on_delete: :nothing)
    end

    create index(:orders, [:user_id])
  end
end
```

The problem is that I was referenceing orders and not users. I've migrated the database:

```
defmodule BarronWatchCompany.Repo.Migrations.AddUserToOrders do
  use Ecto.Migration

  def up do
    drop constraint(:orders, "orders_user_id_fkey")

    alter table(:orders) do
      modify :user_id, references(:users, on_delete: :nothing), null: false
    end
  end
end
```

And I can now create orders :)